# Android: Only make certain part of custom view be clickable

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view, assume it looks like this:

[image: My Custom View]

I would like for my custom view to respond to the onClicks, however the catch is that I would like it to respond to the clicks ONLY on the red portion/circle. Not the whole view.

Is it possible to make to make the text above and the grey portion not clickable?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you rendering the circle using canvas in custom view..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer Carson posted was not exactly what I was looking for as my example was only a simple one, with the reality sometimes it being a lot more difficult and checking the touch locations would be convoluted (imagine multiple views/shapes within the custom view being the click locations).

What I did was in the custom view do a find view by id on the elements of the custom view. Then I did `setOnClickListener(this)` on each element that I would like to be clicked able rather than on the whole view itself, so `mCircle.setOnClickListener(this);` and `mInput.setOnClickListener(this);`, then did `implements View.OnClickListener` for the custom view to handle the actions.

Answer (score 3):

In a custom view, you handle clicks by overriding the `onTouchEvent` method of android's View class. First check that the location the user has clicked is within the circle.  Then normally you would give some feedback on the `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` event to let user know they have clicked, such as highlight the circle. Then on `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you can call your onClick method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {    
        boolean isTouchInCircle = checkTouchInCircle(event.getX(), event.getY());
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (isTouchInCircle) {
                    circleColor = highlightColor;
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (isTouchInCircle) {
                    circleColor = highlightColor;
                } else {
                    circleColor = normalColor
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (isTouchInCircle) {
                    onClickCircle();
                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

// Circle click zone approximated as a square
private boolean checkTouchInCircle(float touchX, float touchY) {
    if (touchX < circleCenterX + circleRadius
          && touchX > circleCenterX - circleRadius
          && touchY < circleCenterY + circleRadius
          && touchY > circleCenterY - circleRadius) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```